# How to extract text from embedded document in Python

Tags: python, html

I want to extract text from some URLS using Python, but I wasn't able to get anything from BeautifulSoup as the documents' HTML only includes an imbedded ID. Here is an example of a file that I would like to extract the text from: [Example](http://investors.yum.com/Cache/1001242026.PDF?O=PDF&T=&Y=&D=&FID=1001242026&iid=4025819)

Any ideas on how to extract the text from that URL?

Here is an example of code which just produces gibberish:

```
r = sessions.get("http://investors.yum.com/Cache/1001242026.PDF? O=PDF&T=&Y=&D=&FID=1001242026&iid=4025819")
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Edited it to show the method I tried using BeautifulSoup. If you go to the link and inspect, you can see the issue. Instead of having the text within the HTML, it just has a single link.

Comment: That's not an html page, that's a PDF document. You can use something to pull the document off the site, then use something like [pypdf2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) to try to parse it

Comment: Do you know if I'd have to download all the PDFs in order to process them usnig pypdf2? Ideally, I'd like to be able to just grab the text with the URLs, without taking up any disk space.

Comment: If you create your parsing as a function, then you can run through the PDFs and parse them in memory

Comment: Alright, I think i've got it figured out. Thanks so much for the help!